# why I'm getting two buttons with same style as previously imported on other component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that is returning an array which contains 2 name and email , I understand that it will return both of them but I don't understand why it returns two buttons although I added single tag and also buttons appears with same style that I imported to the previous component(which has prop) , why ?

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/contactlist.css';
const ContactList =  (props) => {
    const renderContactList = props.contacts.map(contact=>{
         return(
             <div className="item">
                 <div className="content">
                     <div>
                     <div className="name">{contact.name}</div>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                     <div className="mail">{contact.email}</div>
                     <button>Delete</button>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         );
    });
   return(
         <div className="celled-list">
             {renderContactList}
         </div>
   );
}
export default ContactList;
```

and this is the component that has an array and prop

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import AddContact from './AddContact';
import ContactList from './ContactList';
function App() {
  const contacts = [
    {
      id : 1,
      name : "someone",
      email: "something@yahoo.com"
    },
    {
       id  : 2,
      name : "someone1",
      email: "something@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
  return (
    <div>
          <Header/>
          <AddContact/>
          <ContactList contacts={contacts}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-torvalds-f3uoq)

Comment: because you iterate into map

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya what can I do instead ? will it solve styling issue ?

Comment: what you want  to achieve?

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya getting one button without any styling , because I'm getting 2 buttons with the styles that I used on other component and never imported to my current component

Comment: Seems you have 2 buttons because you are mapping a delete button for each element in the passed `contact` prop array. Can you clarify what "with same style as previously imported on other component?" means? What other component? What previous import?

Comment: @DrewReese  I've imported CSS style to my `AddContact.js` the component which added to `App.js` (<AddContact/>) , I have never added any style to my `App.js`  or `ContactList.js` but the buttons are appearing with same style as in `AddContact.js` which has nothing to do with my `ContactList.js`

Comment: This is because CSS is globally available. When you import a .css file in a react component file it doesn't limit it to *just* that file's component code. You seem to be asking about several things, please try to limit the scope of your question to be more focused.

Comment: @DrewReese really ?! maybe it will address my question , please help me , how can I limit the CSS for each individual component ?

Comment: You can use css-in-js, since there are multiple solutions out there this can tend to be opinionated, but this [thorough analysis of css-in-js](https://css-tricks.com/a-thorough-analysis-of-css-in-js/) may be helpful. I use, and really like, [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/).

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you , it was really helpful , personally I liked modular way of styling that I find out in your document , what do you think about modular way? it is not written directly in your document btw but I found it from snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 <kbd>Delete</kbd> buttons because you `map` your array to return an `HTML` which contains a button. Since you have 2 items in your `contacts` prop, you will have 2 buttons.

### `ContactList.js`

```
  const renderContactList = props.contacts.map((contact) => {
    return (
            { /* . . . . //other elements */ }
            <button>Delete</button> {/* this is your button */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Now, if you want to have only 1 button, obviously you need to put it outside the `.map` function so it wont be included in the loop.

### `ContactList.js`

```
  const renderContactList = props.contacts.map((contact) => {
    return (
            { /* . . . . //other elements */ }
            {/* remove your button from here */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="celled-list">
      {renderContactList}
      <button>Delete</button> {/* transfer your button here */}
    </div>
  );
```

Here's a working [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-kalam-hr2c6?file=/src/ContactList.js).

Comment: thank you , but what about styling ? I'm getting buttons with same style as `AddContact .js` , which has nothing to do with contact list ?

Comment: @rEActor, you need to check your css rules. Maybe the same rule applies the `ContactList` buttons as with the `AddContact` buttons. Maybe include the CSS affecting the buttons in your question as well so we can check. But the point is there. Check your css.